# Unparseable date error in Pentaho

Tags: mysql, oracle11g, pentaho, date-parsing

I am using Pentaho to insert and update a table in Mysql.

Source database being oracle 11g and destination is Mysql database.

The query for getting max syncronization time from oracle is

SELECT
  max(SYNC_TIME) AS LST
FROM Abc_ADM.ORA_SYNC_STATS

where SYNC_TIME is of Timestamp(6) datatype in Oracle in format 01-FEB-70 12.00.00.000000000 AM.

when i use this query and run the job i get error-
could not convert string [${LST}] to date using format [yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:ss:SS] on offset location 0
unparseable date [${LST}]

What is that i am declaring wrong? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pentaho is asking for a date-format like

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:ss:SS
```

But your Oracle-Output is different:

```
01-FEB-70 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

For Pentaho its a string, no date at all.

It should work by telling Pentaho the Date-Format:

```
dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss
```

- Do this in an input-Step
- or by using a select-values ("Meta-data") step after your input

Important:
Type should be "Date" and Format: dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss

I can't post screenshots where you could have seen that it works for me.

T  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AuPW.jpg